# AJAX to Python call prints the actual script, not the requested info

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

A bit of a beginner (go easy on me), but I'm at a loss, for some reason when I make an simple ajax call the response prints the actual script and not the requested request.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(function()
            {
                $('#clickme').click(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/js/getData.py",
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype:"json",
                        data: {'key':'value','key2':'value2'},
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log('Success!!!!');
                            var data = response;
                            console.log("response.message: " + response.message);
                            console.log("response.keys: " + response.keys);
                            console.log("response.data: " + response.data);
                            console.log("response: " + response);
                            //$('#mommy').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="clickme"> click me </button>
    <div id="mommy"></div>
</body>
```

This is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")


result = {}
result['success'] = True
result['message'] = "The command Completed Successfully"
result['keys'] = ",".join(fs.keys())

d = {}
for k in fs.keys():
    d[k] = fs.getvalue(k)

result['data'] = d

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close()
```

This is what the output looks like if you just run the getData.py:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "keys": "", 
 "message": "The command Completed Successfully", 
 "data": {}, 
 "success": true
}
```

This is the console output:

```
"Success!!!!" simple.html:19
"response.message: undefined" simple.html:21
"response.keys: undefined" simple.html:22
"response.data: undefined" simple.html:23
"response: #!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")


result = {}
result['success'] = True
result['message'] = "The command Completed Successfully"
result['keys'] = ",".join(fs.keys())

d = {}
for k in fs.keys():
    d[k] = fs.getvalue(k)

result['data'] = d

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close() 
" simple.html:24
```

Comment: Take a look at [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/).

Comment: It seems likely that the webserver is not configured correctly to *run* the script and is instead simply serving the contents of the file itself.  Instructions for changing this will depend a lot on what sort of hosting environment you are using.  If this doesn't mean anything to you, it is probably a good idea to start with an existing python web framework like bottle (as suggested by f p) instead of straight CGI.

Comment: I'll looking at bottle now, it looks promising, but am still curious about this issue. The server is a clean apache2 running on ubuntu (in VM box on win32). Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: There is unfortunately not a single short, easy answer on this.  For example, it depends on what Apache module you are using to run CGI.  For one example of this, see here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

On the other hand, if you do end up wanting to use a framework, you'll most likely want to use mod_wsgi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server isn't set up to serve Python scripts so instead of running the Python script it is giving it's contents back just like any other file (html, css, png, ...)

The way to get your server to run the python scripts will change depending on your server. Check the Python docs [HOWTO Use Python in the Web](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html) to get started.

Comment: I hear, the documentation is extensive and I spent some time on it, but I'm still not clear how to get this done on ubnuntu/apache. The simple test file (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#simple-script-for-testing-cgi) threw the script back at me in form of a download. So I agree that it looks like apache doesn't know how to execute it. Ideas?